# How to set lookup value to a N:1 relationship record and then create it

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, workflow-activity

There use to be a 1:N relationship between Contact (contact) and Car Details(cir_cardetails) - I have now passing a parameter for Contact as a lookup for Car Details like below

```
public static DependencyProperty ContactProperty =   
DependencyProperty.Register("Contact", typeof(Lookup), typeof(CreateCardetails));

 [CrmInput("Contact ID")]
    [CrmReferenceTarget("contact")]
    public Lookup Contact
    {
        get
        {
            return (Lookup)base.GetValue(ContactProperty);
        }
        set
        {

            base.SetValue(ContactProperty, value);
        }
    }

protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute(ActivityExecutionContext  
executionContext)
    {

    ----------------------

     ---------------------

      ---------------------

       Guid contactId = ((Lookup)base.GetValue(ContactProperty)).Value;

    Lookup lookup = new Lookup();
            lookup.Value = contactId;
            lookup.type = "contact";

            //Create an car details record which will be linked to the contact record
            DynamicEntity cardetails = new DynamicEntity("cir_cardetails");

            cardetails["cir_carsdetailsid"] = lookup;

            //Setting the picklist value of Model

             Picklist modelPickList = new Picklist();
             modelPickList.Value = model.Value;
          cardetails.Properties.Add(new PicklistProperty("cir_model",modelPickList));

           //Creating the car details record
            Guid carkey = crmService.Create(cardetails);



}
```

But Now I want to set this GUID value (lookup) to Car details record and then create the Car details record. Is that right that I did in above code like

```
Lookup lookup = new Lookup();
lookup.Value = contactId;
lookup.type = "contact";

DynamicEntity cardetails = new DynamicEntity("cir_cardetails");

cardetails["cir_carsdetailsid"] = lookup;
```

Please help how I will be able to set lookup value.

Comment: What is cir_carsdetailsid on the cir_cardetails entity?  Is it the primary key, Guid, field or the contact lookup field?  The reason I ask is entity primary key fields are by default entityname + id unless you manually change them.

Comment: cir_cardetails is an relation entity..Where there is a lookup field cir_carsdetailsid in which I want to set Contact(contact) record.

Comment: What you have looks correct.  Are you getting an error or something when running it?

Comment: But I had a doubt about that why I am creating a new loolup when I have already input lookup from  [CrmReferenceTarget("contact")]public Lookup Contact{}. Can't I assign this to like cardetails["cir_carsdetailsid"] = Contact;. Probably this will then save the time.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that as well.  Essentially all a lookup field stores in the DB is the Guid and sometimes the type.  So as long as your Lookup object has those two properties you should be fine.

Comment: I didn't check this now. I'll now create a complete Custom Workflow activity for it and deploy using Plugin registration tool. I'll then use it in Workflow on Dynamics CRM 4.0. Again one more question once after registering the plugin I'm restarting the server to make this run properly. Is there any alternate way to achieve this something like if I restart the IIS instead of restarting the server to make it work properly.

Comment: When deploying a plugin to the server you should just have to restart IIS.  However if you have multiple webservers you will have to do it on each one.  Also if you are deploying WF activity updates you will also have to restart the Async Service as well as IIS.